# What happens during circuit creation if one OR fails?

Tags: protocol

Hey just looking for some clarification on something.

When creating a standard three hop circuit, if for some reason the client (Alice) does not receive a response from the third OR does she retry the same or assume the packet had gotten lost ?

Or chooses a new circuit completely?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to section 5.1 [1] of tor's specification. During the last `CREATE`

`On failure, a server sends a
   DESTROY cell to tear down the circuit.`

Specifically, Section 5.4 [2] states the circuit will be torn-down by sending `DESTROY` back towards the client with the appropriate error code [3] in the payload.

> Or chooses a new circuit completely ?

Correct. From Section 2.5 [4] of the path specification

`Requests that might have been
   supported by the pending circuit thus become unsupported, and a new
   circuit needs to be constructed.`

[1] [Section 5.1](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/tor-spec.txt#n735) 
[2] [Section 5.4](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/tor-spec.txt#n1099) 
[3] [Error codes](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/tor-spec.txt#n1144) 
[4] [Section 2.5](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/path-spec.txt#n516)